# Problema com cache em jogos flash

Tags: html5, flash, jogos

Eu estou monitorando um site em um projeto da faculdade e percebi que, no momento em que eu abro um certo jogo, ele dá um erro, variando o erro de jogo pra jogo, alguns não carregam, alguns demoram muito pra carregar, outro dá erro ao entrar no jogo, como alguns bugs, mas eu percebi que apertando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ele para com os erros, mas algumas vezes eu tenho que aperta <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> diversas vezes, e dessa maneira eu gostaria de saber se é possível no código html mudar isso, fazendo com que elimine esse erro ou elimine o cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desabilitar o cache dos navegadores, você pode combinar algumas meta *tags*:

```
<!-- 
   Informa ao navegador que não é pra armazenar nenhum tipo de cache 
   Teoricamente só essa opção já resolveria o problema
   Versão HTTP: 1.1
-->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<!-- 
   Informa que o cache é pra expirar no dia 1 de janeiro de 1980  
   Ou seja, o cache já expirou e é pra deletar tudo
-->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<!-- 
   Basicamente o mesmo que http-equiv:cache-control, exceto que  
   essa meta é para versão HTTP 1.0
-->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Para mais detalhes sobre as meta *tags*, pode ler detalhes [neste link  <sup>EN</sup>](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html#pragma).

[Resposta Original <sup>EN</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/3497987)

Outro problema também pode ser a velocidade de conexão, então o navegador não está conseguindo baixar todos os arquivos necessários para a execução do aplicativo. E isto não poderia ser resolvido com *tags* HTML, exceto que a compressão dos arquivos ajudaria.

Comment: eu usei as tags que você me passou, mas não resolveu aqui, assim, eu aperto ctrl+f5 e volta a funcionar, mas apertando apenas f5 ele nao roda as vezes, não sei dizer qual o problema exato.

Comment: Opa @GabrielSilva, faça o seguinte, inspecione o código usando o inspetor de algum navegador, e na aba Network (Rede no IE), verifique se há alguma disparidade de quando funciona e quando não funciona, se tem algum arquivo que não está sendo carregado. Ferramentas: [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network), [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/network), [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bg182326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#A_ferramenta_Rede__CTRL___4_)

Comment: Então, quando isso ocorre ele fala que não esta sendo carregado a arquivo .swf que é do jogo em flash, mas após eu dar um ctrl + F5 ele funciona as vezes, as vezes não.

Comment: Eu fiz oque você tinha dito e não aparece nada no network(eu to usando chrome) e no console ele da o erro que o arquivo não esta sendo carregado.

Comment: @GabrielSilva você tem que abrir o inspetor e depois atualizar a página.

Comment: No network o unico problema que está dando é que não está aparecendo a imagem de warning, mas tirando isso ta tudo correto, eu não consigo achar a explicação para esse bug, pois tem vez que funciona tem vez que não funciona o jogo em flash, não sei dizer muito bem

Comment: @Gabrielsilva tem algum link que a gente possa ver e testar?

Comment: Sim Kadu, 
http://www.cienciaweb.com.br/site/jogos/

Comment: dai tem a barra de jogos em cima, dai estão bugando vários, e assim, se vocês entrar no jogo da matematica e o circuitrohms pode ser que não aconteça ai mas na hora de jogar ele da erro, fica piscando tudo, dai vc da ctrl + f5 algumas vezes e ele volta ao normal.

No console ele da o seguinte erro: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET e aparece o link do jogo ao lado

Comment: @GabrielSilva não consegui simular o problema aqui, tentei varias vezes e ele sempre carrega. O único problema que vi foi um erro no console `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` no arquivo `js.min.js` linha 6. Como eu disse na resposta, pode ser problema de conexão com a internet. Testa em outras redes, com provedores e velocidade diferentes.

Comment: Todos os jogos abriram corretamente? nenhum ficou carregando sem a necessidade de apertar f5? o jogo da matematica mesmo depois de apertar em jogar ele não está dando problema?nem o do circuitrohmns?

Comment: Sim @GabrielSilva, funciona corretamente, joguei um pouco de cada e todos funcionaram.

Comment: A certo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

é que eu ja acessei em uma internet de 90mb, uma de 15mb e uma de 1mb, e nem sempre funciona, dependendo do lugar nao funciona direito, e isso é ruim para o publico, e quando da erro e eu uso o inspecionar elemento ele da aquele erro citado em cima no console e aparece o link do jogo, mas muito obrigado.